# What is the term for improving an object/class model?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, terminology

How do you call it when your buddy designs a class Dinosaur, that represents at the same time prehistoric dinosaurs (animals), contemporary robotic dinosaurs (toys) and US laws regarding keeping such animals and/or robots, and you come and break it down into classes DinosaurProper, DinosaurRobot, ExoticPetKeepingInUS and RobotOwnershipInUS? What is the smartass catchphrase or catchword for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactoring aimed at satisfying the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP).

Comment: Pretty please, any more cool words? Any way to say it in one, or 2 words? Something cool, like "Law of Demeter"? (Actually, SRP is quite good, I'm just begging because I'm stuck writing a publication here.)

Answer (score 1):

Depdning on the exact structure of the initial design it may be sometimes called
[ReplaceTypeCodeWithSubclasses](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithSubclasses.html) or [ExtractSubclass](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractSubclass.html)

Comment: In this case, it's not even a subclases, mixing dinosaurs with robot dinosaurs is a case of mixing false friends in one class, and mine is the act of exposing and correcting it.